# How to turn the whole widget into image using RepaintBoundary in flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, render

I'm using the flutter class `RepaintBoundary` to export an image out of my flutter widget, it worked great until the list inside this widget extended the visible part in my devices, so I found out that `RepaintBoundary` only capture the visible part of the widget, is there any way to capture the whole widget. ??

here is the code am using to capture the widget

```dart
 Future<Uint8List> _capturePng(context) async {
    try {
      print('inside');
      RenderRepaintBoundary boundary =
          _globalKey.currentContext.findRenderObject();
      ui.Image image = await boundary.toImage(pixelRatio: 3.0);
      ByteData byteData =
          await image.toByteData(format: ui.ImageByteFormat.png);
      var pngBytes = byteData.buffer.asUint8List();
      var bs64 = base64Encode(pngBytes);
      print(pngBytes);
      PrintingServices().printTestTicket(pngBytes);
      isLoading = false;
      print(bs64);
      setState(() {});
      return pngBytes;
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
      return null;
    }
  }
```

And here is the code of the widget itself:

```dart
                  RepaintBoundary(
                    key: _globalKey,
                    child: Container(
                      width: 305.36224281729,
                      color: Colors.white,
                      child: ListView(
                        children: [
                          Image.memory(logoBytes),
                          Text(
                            '$companyName',
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 40, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                          ),
                          Text(
                            'Welcome to $companyName',
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 20,
                            ),
                          ),
                          Text(
                            'Have a nice day',
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 20,
                            ),
                          ),
                          Text(
                            '$branchName',
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 20,
                            ),
                          ),
                          Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(32, 8, 32, 16),
                            child: Divider(
                              thickness: 5,
                              color: Colors.black,
                            ),
                          ),
                          Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                            child: Row(
                              children: [
                                Text(
                                  'Date:',
                                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12),
                                ),
                                Text(
                                  " ${DateTime.now().day} / ${DateTime.now().month} / ${DateTime.now().year}",
                                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                          Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                            child: Row(
                              children: [
                                Text(
                                  'Time:',
                                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12),
                                ),
                                Text(
                                  " ${DateTime.now().hour} : ${DateTime.now().minute}",
                                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                          Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                            child: Row(
                              children: [
                                Text(
                                  'Taken By:',
                                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12),
                                ),
                                Text(
                                  " $employeeName",
                                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                          Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                            child: Table(
                              columnWidths: {1: FractionColumnWidth(.5)},
                              border: TableBorder.all(color: Colors.black),
                              defaultVerticalAlignment:
                                  TableCellVerticalAlignment.middle,
                              children: itemTable,
                            ),
                          ),
                          Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                            child: Table(
                              columnWidths: {1: FractionColumnWidth(.5)},
                              border: TableBorder.all(color: Colors.black),
                              defaultVerticalAlignment:
                                  TableCellVerticalAlignment.middle,
                              children: [
                                TableRow(children: [
                                  Padding(
                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                    child: Text('SUBTOTAL'),
                                  ),
                                  Padding(
                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                    child: Text('$total'),
                                  ),
                                ]),
                                TableRow(children: [
                                  Padding(
                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                    child: Text('VAT'),
                                  ),
                                  Padding(
                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                    child: Text('00.00'),
                                  ),
                                ]),
                                TableRow(children: [
                                  Padding(
                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                    child: Text(
                                      'TOTAL',
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  Padding(
                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                    child: Text(
                                      '$total',
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ]),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                          Divider(
                            thickness: 3,
                            color: Colors.black,
                          ),
                          Text('Thank you for choosing $companyName'),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
```

[image]

in this image you can see my full widget, if the table has an extra 1 item, the footer part is not visible and not being printed anymore !! any help with this ??

Comment: Would you try using 'SingleChildScrollView' rather than 'ListView'?
I knew that 'ListView' renders only visible items on the screen. There is a some package what you want.https://pub.dev/packages/screenshot

Comment: how can we create jpg image? png image is transparent and mixed with background. Please share any suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to generate a pdf file over printing the items displayed on screen as some parts may get cut off. The [pdf](https://pub.dev/packages/pdf) plugin can be used to generate the item to be printed. With this approach, you have the option to save the page that you're going to print for archive.

To use, just add the widgets that you're going print inside a pdf `Document`.

```dart
final pdf = pw.Document();

pdf.addPage(pw.Page(
    pageFormat: PdfPageFormat.a4,
    build: (pw.Context context) {
      return // Add the Widgets here
      ); 
    }
));
```